# creating a legend inside loop

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to get a legend to label multiple plots generated inside a for loop.  I've read several feeds on this topic. I'm not sure why they all seem so unclear, but I still can't figure out a way to get it to work.

```
x=0:.2:13;
y=zeros(4,length(x));
slope=zeros(1,4);
strings=zeros(1,4);
hold on
grid on

for cnt=1:4

slope(cnt)=-omega(cnt)/trq(cnt);

y(cnt,:)=x*slope(cnt)+omega(cnt);

plot(x,y(cnt,:))

str=sprintf('%f volts',V(cnt));
legend(str)
end

axis([0 .05 0 300])
```

I've tried moving the legend command outside the loop, and I've tried making an array of strings inside the loop.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The function `legend` expects a collection of strings whereas you are currently only passing in one string value on each call. Therefore, you should accumulate the strings you want as legends within the loop and then call `legend` outside of the loop with that collection.

```
str = cell(1,4); %initialize a cell array to hold the legend strings

for
    .
    .
    .
    str{cnt}=sprintf('%f volts',V(cnt)); %insert text into the appropriate cells
end
legend(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with creating a legend from strings is that if you turn the legend off and then you turn it back on again, your custom string is gone. Therefore, I suggest setting the 'DisplayName' property of graphics objects:

```
x=0:.2:13;
y=zeros(4,length(x));
slope=zeros(1,4);
hold on


for cnt=1:4
slope(cnt)=-omega(cnt)/trq(cnt);
y(cnt,:)=x*slope(cnt)+omega(cnt);

plot(x,y(cnt,:),'DisplayName',sprintf('%f volts',V(cnt)))

end

%# finish the figure
grid on
axis([0 .05 0 300])
legend('show')
```